# Restructure object of object to an json data

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I have the following JSON data like this i tried iterating it with object.entries

```
 {
  "1245": {
    "case_id": "1245",
    "nodes": 11,
    "others": {
      "hops": "1"
    },
    "status": "COMPLETE"
  }
}
```

I would like it to be reconstructed in the following JSON format using javscript:
expected output like :

```
{
  data :[
   case_id:'123",
   nodes:11,
   status: "COMPLETE",
   hops:1,
  ]
}
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: `{ data: Object.values(INPUT).map(({ others, ...x }) => ({ ...x, ...others })) }`

Comment: do you really want an **array** with properties?

Comment: @Christian i ittirated the object using object.entries

Comment: The expected output is neither a valid JSON nor a valid object literal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fact that your data is structured as a key/value pair, means that you will need to use `Object.keys` to iterate over the data before you are able to map it into an array. You will then need to construct your object so that it has "data" as the property for the mapped array.

```
const yourData = { "1245": {
    "case_id": "1245",
    "nodes": 11,
    "others": {
      "hops": "1"
    },
    "status": "COMPLETE"
  }
}

const theArrayYouWant = Object.keys(yourData).map((entry) => {
  return {
     case_id: yourData[entry].case_id,
     nodes: yourData[entry].nodes,
     status: yourData[entry].status,
     hops: yourData[entry].others.hops,
  };
});

const yourDataType = { data: theArrayYouWant };
```